# Declare an object with keys being assigned value of other keys?

Tags: javascript

Is there a better title for this?

Okay, is something like this legal?

```
var myobj = {
    key1: "val1",
    key2: this.key1
};
```

I haven't tried it, but I'm looking for a way to have identical values for separate keys in an object, preferably in a concise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is legal but doesn't do what you mean. When evaluating the `key:...` part `this` is not bound to the yet-non-existent object, but to the context where myobj is being built. You have to store the value in a variable and then using the variable... like:

```
var kv = "val1";
var myobj = {
    key1: kv,
    key2: kv
};
```

note that here you're not creating a *closure* if this is your fear. That only happens for `function` expressions

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var myobj = {};
myobj['key2'] = (myobj['key1'] = 'val1');
```

Since in javascript, value assignment also returns the value as well, so you can be somewhat concise.